# Highlighting matches in Vim over an inverted pattern

Tags: vim

How may I highlight in Vim with the :match command the text that does not matches with the given pattern?

So, I want the opposite of:

```
:match myGroup /foo/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do something like:

```
:match myBaseHighlight /foo/
:2match myGroup /./
```

where `myBaseHighlight` is defined to be your default appearance -- white on black, or whatever.  `:match` will override `:2match`, so everything other than `/foo/` will get the `myGroup` highlight.